# Export my SharePoint aspx page to a PDF file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf, sharepoint

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection , and using the SharePoint designer I have manually added a link named “Print to PDF” as follow:-

[image]

But I am trying to implement the link functionalities, so when the user clink on the link, the page content (mainly any html components that are inside the rich text ) should be displayed inside a pdf file?

Can anyone advice how I can achieve this ,, can I write a javaScript code which can do the work ? Thanks

Comment: What sharepoint version are you using? Foundation? Server? Pdf conversion is usually made by using word automation services and templates.

Comment: i am using SharePoint 2013 server.

Comment: And you did consider using word automation for conversion? It is a bit unclear of what you want to do. Please specify as a list or similar

Comment: i want to have a link named "convert to PDF" inside all the wiki pages, where users can convert any wiki page inside our Enterprise Wiki site collection, to be exported as PDF file. so let say UserA is viewing page named 123 , then if he clicks on the "Export to PDF", a pdf file should open containing the Wiki page content (tet,images, etc), and i user can simply save the pdf file to his machine  .

Comment: well, word automation services i the sharepoint way. You will have to do some development.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an ASPX page (actually preferably an ASHX handler) that does the work for you by accepting an URL to convert, which you then pass into a third party HTML to PDF library. The generated PDF file can then be returned to the user's browser.

Alternatively, have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/converting-any-file-to-pdf-using-simple.html) (*that I wrote, so big fat disclaimer about me being biased*) that shows how you can buy a product off the shelf that does all the work for you.

You can read [more about it here](http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/21768596-Converting-SharePoint-pages-HTML).

BTW, for questions related to SharePoint you may want to consider using [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com).